# Spring 4 and generics

Tags: spring, generics

I am upgrading from Spring 3 to Spring 4.
The following code snippet works in Spring 3, but does not work in Spring 4.

```
class GenericParent {}

class GenericChild extends GenericParent {}

interface IntfA<T extends GenericParent> {}

interface IntfB extends IntfA<GenericChild> {}

class ImplB implements IntfB {}

class SomeClass {
  @Autowired
  IntfA<GenericParent> autowired;
}
```

Bean is defined as follows:

```
<bean class="example.ImplB" />
```

Spring 4 cannot match

```
@Autowired
IntfA<GenericParent> autowired;
```

with definition

```
<bean class="example.ImplB" />
```

I guess Spring finds that ImplB implements

```
IntfA<GenericChild>
```

and cannot match it with

```
IntfA<GenericParent>
```

But it works in Spring 3.

The solution to that is changing IntfB definition to

```
IntfB extends IntfA<GenericParent>
```

but I would like to avoid this.
Is there a way to make this work without changing the generic type ? 
Maybe some additional bean description is required or some additional annotation ?

Comment: You can put the error trace?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [example.IntfA] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: did you tried to change @Autowired for another annotation like @Resource(....)?, i had some problem similar with spring 4, but i dont remember how i fixed

Comment: Because yes the problem is that spring not find the definition that match with IntfA<GenericParent> for make the autowired, so i think if you put @ Resource and some name that will fix the problem

Comment: Even if bean name is provided with Qualifier or Resource Spring 4 does not match it. Exception is the same.